# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sir' of 'Money.Money(string)'

Tags: c#, syntax-error

So, I'm new to C# and Object Programming and I am having a small Issue.

In the base class I have this(which basically converts string to double[]:

```
namespace PersonalSpendings
{
    class Money
    {
        private decimal money { get; set; }
        public Money(string str)
        {
            //conversion from string to double[]
            int j = 0;
            string[] str2 = str.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', '.' },         
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) ;
            double[] strFinal = { '0', '0', '0' };
            foreach(string i in str2)
            {
                strFinal[j] = double.Parse(i);
                j++;
            }
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

and I don't understand why it won't let me create another constructer(with different parameters):

```
namespace PersonalSpendings
{
    class Income: Money
    {
        public Income(double amount, string name)
        {

        }
        public Income(string str) : base(str)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

It has an issue with the first constructor:(double amount, string name).

Can't I create constructors that are specific to my derived class?

Comment: what is issue? what error you are facing while creating constructor with two parameters

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, but since your base class has only a single constructor with a parameter, you will need to call that from any constructor in your derived class.

```
    public Income(double amount, string name) : base(/* something */)
    {

    }
    public Income(string str) : base(str)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public Income(double amount, string name)
{
    ...
}
```

equals to

```
public Income(double amount, string name) : base() // try to call Money()
{
    ...
}
```

because every constructor calls a base class constructor untill object() is reached. If one does not provide a call to a base constructor manually the compiler puts a call to parameterless constructor. So in your code you try to call parameterless constructor Money(), but you do not have any. This is the issue.
Possible solution is:

```
public Income(double amount, string name) : base(name)
{
    ...
}
```

or provide Money with parameterless constructor.